# submit deletes the input file value in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to trigger a click in an input file with jquery. Everything ok until the moment when I press the submit button, then the input value is deleted and the submit event canceled. This, as usual, is only happening in IE8/IE9 (firefox/chrome works)

This is the code: http://jsbin.com/iqeyom/1

Why I'm doing this? Because I'm hiding the input file and triggering the file selection window with a link. In the given link is not hidden just for showing purposes. Any clue? thanks in advance

Comment: This may be this way due to security restrictions. You need a real click to trigger the upload, not a scripted one.

Comment: Is your `form` using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @Gromer not in the example given, but in my original project is included: `<form class="form-horizontal" id="edit_postulant_info_3" action="/postulant/information" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" checkedByCssHelper="true" _submit_attached="true" sizset="0" jQuery17209259087474215457="84" sizcache05803466987044774="110">`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
  $('#form_file').trigger('submit');
  //do whatever you need...
});
```

Comment: But that doesn't open the file selection window, doesn't trigger a click in the file input and then allow me to submit without clean the input file. That's what I want